# Install GuixSD using an existing Linux system

Tags: system-installation, guixsd

I want to install Guix System Distribution (or GuixSD, or just Guix) alongside some other distros. The problem is, Guix doesn't recognise Realtek drivers, which are nonfree, so I can't use WiFi. I can install Guix with Ethernet, but it is very unstable, so I want to install it with my existing Debian (buster) installation so I can then add the Nonguix channel and install the drivers. Problem is, I don't really know how.

I'm pretty sure it includes installing Guix onto Debian, installing some packages, and strapping GuixSD onto the root (atleast, that's how NixOS does it, which Guix is inspired by) or it includes chrooting into the ISO.

I would appreciate any help possible.

### System Info

```
# neofetch # some info was filtered

root@deblugo 
--------------- 
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) x86_64 
Host: HP Notebook 
Kernel: 4.19.0-16-amd64 
Packages: 1624 (dpkg) 
Shell: bash 5.0.3  
CPU: Intel Celeron N3060 (2) @ 2.480GHz 
GPU: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx 
Memory: 1931MiB / 3803MiB 

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

# uname -a
Linux deblugo 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Installing on Debian

From GNU Guix Reference Manual, [2 Installation](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/html_node/Installation.html#Installation):

> | Note |
> | --- |
> | We recommend the use of this [shell installer script](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/plain/etc/guix-install.sh) to install Guix on top of a running GNU/Linux system, thereafter called a *foreign distro*. The script automates the download, installation, and initial configuration of Guix. It should be run as the root user. |

Here is a `bash` one-liner command for installing Guix on Debian buster:

```bash
bash <(wget -qO- https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guix.git/plain/etc/guix-install.sh)
```

### Nonguix channel installation

Adapted instructions from the [Nonguix project page](https://gitlab.com/nonguix/nonguix):

Nonguix can be installed as a [Guix channel](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Channels.html). To do so, add it to `~/.config/guix/channels.scm`:

```scheme
(cons* (channel
        (name 'nonguix)
        (url "https://gitlab.com/nonguix/nonguix")
        ;; Enable signature verification:
        (introduction
         (make-channel-introduction
          "897c1a470da759236cc11798f4e0a5f7d4d59fbc"
          (openpgp-fingerprint
           "2A39 3FFF 68F4 EF7A 3D29  12AF 6F51 20A0 22FB B2D5"))))
       %default-channels)
```

Then run `guix pull`.

### Using Nonfree Firmware and Drivers

To use Guix System with the standard Linux kernel and nonfree firmware, edit the kernel and firmware fields of the operating-system definition in `config.scm`:

```scheme
;; Import nonfree linux module.
(use-modules (nongnu packages linux)
             (nongnu system linux-initrd))

(operating-system
  (kernel linux)
  (initrd microcode-initrd)
  (firmware (list linux-firmware))
  ...
  )
```

If you only need firmware for your Realtek network device, you may be able to save disk space by using a smaller firmware package instead:

```scheme
(firmware (cons* iwlwifi-firmware
                 %base-firmware))
```

Then of course, run `sudo guix system reconfigure /etc/config.scm` to apply your configuration.

### Installation image

As you said, the official Guix installation image won’t work for your hardware, so you can generate an installation image running the nonfree Linux kernel and nonfree firmware with the following command:

```bash
guix system image --image-size=7.2GiB /path/to/this/channel/nongnu/system/install.scm
```

As indicated bellow, you will need to run `guix pull` to download the Nonguix package descriptions. Some free space on your USB thumbdrive is required for this operation to succeed. The above `--image-size` option allows you to specify the size of the image and, as such, to allocate free space to it. The given value is purely indicative — it obviously depends on your thumbdrive capacity.

Then you can write the generated disk image to a USB thumbdrive with:

| Note |
| --- |
| This example assumes your thumbdrive is recognized by Linux as `/dev/sdb`. |

```bash
dd if=/path/to/disk-image of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress oflag=sync
```

The installation media produced by the above method does not automatically configure your channels specification.  You need to add Nonguix “manually” into `/etc/guix/channels.scm` and then run `guix pull` to make Guix aware of Nonguix scheme libraries. Below is Guile scheme code to include Nonguix in the channel specification.

```scheme
(use-modules (ice-9 pretty-print))
(with-output-to-file "/etc/guix/channels.scm"
  (lambda _
    (pretty-print
     '(cons*
       (channel (name 'nonguix)
        (url "https://gitlab.com/nonguix/nonguix"))
       %default-channels))))
```

As mentioned in [issue 82](https://gitlab.com/nonguix/nonguix/-/issues/82), the modules for Realtek network devices have been included since `kernel-linux-5.11`:

> The firmware files should be in `realtek-firmware` or the `linux-firmware` package.
> But I guess we need to build the `RTW88` module. So we need to set `CONFIG_RTW88=m` in `upstream guix gnu/packages/aux-files/linux-libre/5.10-x86_64.conf`. [Since] `kernel linux-5.11`, this particular module should now be enabled by default...